# Delete attached images from posts

Tags: posts, images, attachments

I exported posts from site X to Y. But in every post on site X there was image attached to it (not featured image)

```
<a href="http://x" rel="attachment wp-att-25425"><img src="x/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/x" alt="" width="300" height="141" class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-25425" /></a>
```

Is there some way to query all posts on site Y (there are 700 of them) and delete all attachments from posts (i don't need that images)?

Comment: In what way are those attachments added to posts? Is it in the content, or as a featured image/gallery images?

Comment: If you're not able to edit the files as mentioned by @leymannx in the answer below, you can also use the the WP-CLI search-replace function in combination with a regex to erase the images from site Y's database. If using a regex you need to make sure, the markup is always the same, as you may get unexpected results otherwise.

Comment: those attachments are in content

Answer (score 0):

Having that resulting XML file from the export it's just a matter of editing it precisely to get rid of the images before importing it on the other site.

Taking [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) for example it's pretty easy to find and select all occurrences of `[caption` and add a line break before them for example. Same for the closing tag. Then find and select all occurrences of `[caption` again  and in the menu under "Selection" select "Expand selection to line". Then hit delete on your keyboard, done.

Maybe you need to separate all occurrences of `<![CDATA[[caption` (featured images if I'm right) first by replacing them with some custom token to have them excluded by the in-post image search.

Comment: is it possible to give me example (honestly i dont know how to do it )<content:encoded>
    <![CDATA[[:hr]<a href="http:/url" rel="attachment wp-att-29100"><img src="http:/url" alt="" width="300" height="200" class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-29100" /></a>
post text[:]]]>  </content:encoded> ignore {:hr} tags, those are for qtranslate, p.s. they are not featured images, they are simply images inserted into post